# Javascript Básico - como retirar virgula da string

Tags: javascript, string

Estou com uma dúvida que está me consumindo aqui referente a este trechinho de código:

```
let word = "APPLE"
//CONVERTED TO ARRAY
let res = word.slice(3,5)
//RES = LE
let res1 = res.split("")
//REVERSE THE ARRAY NOW IS "E,L"
let res2 = res1.reverse()
//MERGE INTO A STRING
let res3 = res2.toString()
//FINALLY RETURN INTO "E L"
```

Eu quero que saia no console "E L", ao invés "E,L", quero um espaço entre as letras, tentei um tanto de método e não consegui, por favor se alguém puder me ajudar ficarei muito grato

Comment: Não é melhor usar `.join(' ')`?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: res3.join is not a function at <anonymous>:1:6 essa mensagem aparece no console

Comment: É `res2.join`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve ter usado o `.join('')` errado.

```js
let res2 = ["E", "L"]
let res3 = res2.join(' ')
console.log(res3)
```

Código funcional acima.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vou colocar o código integral aqui para vocês poderem analisar melhor:

Comment: Coloquei o código funcional e deu essa mensagem no console: VM116:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: res3 is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
(anonymous) @ VM116:1

Comment: porém ele está completamente certo kkk, copia o código dentro de um novo arquivo .js

Comment: coloquei um print do resultado que obtive

Comment: Estou usando  o plugin do LiveServer, agora quando coloco qualquer nome de variável está retornando o seguinte :CSSKeywordValue
ƒ CSSKeywordValue() { [native code] }

Comment: Valeu reiniciei o pc, criei um novo arquivo e tudo rodou certinho, muito obrigado!